# Efficiently cleaning R from attached objects

Tags: r

I want to initialise some variables from an external data file. One way is to set a file like the following `foo.csv`:

```
var1,var2,var3
value1,value2,value3
```

Then issue:

```
attach(read.csv('foo.csv'))
```

The problem is that in this way `var1, var2, var3` are not shown by `ls()` and most of all `rm(all=ls())` doesn't clean all anymore and `var1, var2, var3` are still there.

As the default position for new objects is '2', I can remove the workspace where this variables live via:

```
detach(pos=2)
```

or simply

```
detach()
```

Since `pos=2` is the default for `detach` too.

But  `detach()` is "too" powerful and it can delete R objects loaded by default. This means that, if one attaches many datasets, removing them with repeated `detach` can lead to delete also default R objects and you have to restart it. Besides the simplicity of the single `rm(all=ls())` goes away.

One solution will be to attach `var1, var2, var3` straight to the the global environment.

Do you know how to do that?

```
attach(read.csv('foo.csv'), pos=1)
```

issues a warning (future error).

```
attach(read.csv('foo.csv'), pos=-1)
```

seems ineffective.

Comment: @Jilber: it is a CSV file, why prepending  the `>`'s?

Comment: It’s a (botched) formatting edit: `>` denotes a block quote on this site. To insert formatted data files on this site, using *code* is more appropriate than a quotation. Jilber should have removed the leading `>` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read the variables straight into the global environment, you can do this:

```
{
  foo<-read.csv('foo.csv')
  for(n in names(foo)) assign(n,foo[[n]],globalenv())
}
```

The braces will prevent `foo` from also being added to the global environment.  You can also make this into a function if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use the named variant of `attach` and `detach`:

```
attach(read.csv(text='var1,var2,var3\nvalue1,value2,value3'),
       name = 'some_name')
```

and

```
detach('some_name')
```

This will prevent mistakes. You’d obviously wrap these two into functions and generate the names automatically in an appropriate manner (the easiest being via a monotonically increasing counter).

Answer (score 1):

What about a 'safer' `attach`?

```
attach<-function(x) {for(n in names(x)) assign(n,x[[n]],globalenv()); names(x)}
```

'Safer' means you can see attached vars with `ls()` and most of all remove them with a single `rm(list=ls())`

Inspired by [mrip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2588184/mrip)